# Analyzing oil and gas well density in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, density

I've started working in Google Earth Engine and am trying to perform density analysis on abandoned and capped oil and gas wells in Louisiana. I have uploaded a CSV of my well database as a Feature Collection point layer, and am trying to start by analyzing how many wells are in each parish.

I have been able to upload the well data and the shapefile of the Louisiana parishes, but all the tutorials I have found include Feature Collections that already have density in certain areas as a property. I'm trying to use GEE to count how many wells are in each parish.

The code I used to include my CSV and parishes is below:

```
JavaScript
Map.centerObject(wells);
Map.addLayer(wells, {color: 'red'}, 'Wells');
Map.addLayer(counties,{
   'color': 'black'
}, 'Counties', false);

var parishes = ee.FeatureCollection(
   'projects/landloss-2324/assets/louisianaparishes');
   
   print(parishes.size());
Map.addLayer(parishes,{
   'color': 'blue'
}, 'parishes');
   
var welltest = parishes.filterBounds(coastalplain);

var filtering = counties.filterBounds(welltest);
Map.addLayer(filtering,{}, 'WellsFilter');
```

I don't think that the filterBounds command has done what I hoped it to. I'm still pretty new to GEE writ large, so I'm not sure if there's a command or known path I'm missing to figure out how to analyze these. What do I add to use GEE to count the number of wells within each parish?